# python subprocess won't play nicely with gsutil copy/move commands

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess, gsutil

In Python I'm using subprocess to call gsutil copy and move commands, but am currently unable to select multiple extensions.

The same gsutil command works at the terminal, but not in python:

```
cmd_gsutil = "sudo gsutil -m mv gs://xyz-ms-media-upload/*.{mp4,jpg} gs://xyz-ms-media-upload/temp/"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_gsutil, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
```

If say there are four filetypes to move but the bucket is empty, the returning gsutil error from terminal is:

```
4 files/objects could not be transferred.
```

Whereas the error returned when run through subprocess is:

```
1 files/objects could not be transferred.
```

So clearly subprocess is mucking up the command somehow...

I could always inefficiently repeat the command for each of the filetypes, but would prefer to get to the bottom of this!

Answer (score 2):

It seems, `/bin/sh` (the default shell) doesn't support `{mp4,jpg}` syntax. 
Pass `executable='/bin/bash'`, to run it as a bash command instead.

You could also run the command without the shell e.g., using `glob` or `fnmatch` modules to get the filenames to construct the `gsutil` command. Note: you should pass the command as a list in this case instead.